# Rails 3. link to images in javascript file don't work in production

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a js file that links to some images but I can't get it to work.

I have tried the js extension like this...

```
case 0: var padImg = 'hs.png'; break;
case 0: var padImg = '/assets/hs.png'; break;
```

I changed the file extension to js.erb and tried this...

```
case 0: var padImg = '<%= asset_path 'hs.png' %>'; break;
```

Then I moved the images to the js folder and it finally worked like this...

```
case 0: var padImg = 'hs.png'; break;
```

The weird thing is, it works in my development environment but it doesn't work on production. Why and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 2):

This syntax is incorrect

```
case 0: var padImg = '<%= asset_path 'hs.png' %>'; break;
```

It should give a JavaScript error.

Try

```
case 0: var padImg = "<%= asset_path 'hs.png' %>"; break;
```

Normally for JavaScript/CoffeeScript and ERB you want to reference the image like

```
$('#logo').attr({
  src: "<%= asset_path('logo.png') %>"
});
```

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html

if that's not it, then what is the production server OS and web server using there if it's different from development?

Is it the only asset pipleine failing?

**Edit**

For Apache\JBoss to reference images in CSS I had to add the path\war name

so if my app root is localhost:3000/MyApp then to reference the image I had to do `url(/MyApp/images/hs.png)`

if you have js.erb you can do it like above and with css.erb you can do `url(<%= asset_path 'hs.png' %>)`

Comment: Tried `"<%= asset_path 'hs.png' %>"` and `"<%= asset_path 'images/hs.png' %>"` and it doesn't work. Production server OS is Debian 6 and Web server is Apache. The asset pipeline is not failing, it's just the images on that are referenced in that js file.

Comment: I analized the HTML and found out I have this on my development machine `<div style="width: 181px; height: 101px; background-image: url(http://localhost:3000/assets/hs.png); background-position: 0px 0px; background-repeat: no-repeat no-repeat; "></div>` but I have this on my production server `<div style="width: 181px; height: 101px; background-image: url(http://apicsmty.org/scheduled_courses/56/jscolor/hs.png); background-position: 0px 0px; background-repeat: no-repeat no-repeat; "></div>` Notice the path to hs.png